US Permanent Resident operating in Canada
I am a US Permanent Resident with an Extra-class license from the FCC. I'm looking to operate when I visit Canada, but everything I'm seeing on the ARRL and RAC sites specifies Citizen.
Are there specific laws/rules that require US Citizenship, and if so, what do they actually say, or is Permanent Residence status sufficient?

Based on https://www.arrl.org/foreign-licenses-operating-in-u-s and a bunch of other sites (say https://www.rac.ca/operating/operation-in-foreign-countries/) I conclude that you must either (1) get a Canadian license, or get a license in your country of citizenship. Both the US and Canada consistently speak of 'citizen' and having your US/Canada passport handy. I'm open to being wrong...

It may matter: what is your country of citizenship?

@webmarc, I'm a British citizen but don't hold a British license.

According to Radio Amateurs of Canada:

In 1952, Canada and the United States signed a Reciprocal Operating Agreement treaty. In the terms of the agreement, visiting Amateurs may operate in the host country in accordance with the rules and regulations of the host country. [...] According to the regulations in both countries, you must be a citizen of the country that issued your Amateur license or certificate in order to take advantage of this reciprocal operating agreement.
[emphasis added]

Further, according to the "Convention Between Canada and the United States of America relating to the Operation by Citizens of either Country of Certain Radio Equipment or Stations in the other Country" hosted on the US FCC site (bizarre capitalization scheme is in the original):

The Government of Canada and the Government of the United States of America, being desirous of establishing rules to permit the citizens of either country, upon certain conditions, to operate etc etc etc

It seems that unless you are a citizen, you are NOT covered by the typical reciprocity that Canadian/US citizens take advantage of.
This does NOT mean that you are out of luck, just that you should probably contact either the RAC or the Innovation, Science and Economic Development Canada (ISED; formerly Industry Canada) to see if there is a different program under which you might be eligible.

ISED specifically says there's no nationality requirement on getting a Canadian license, so that's probably the easiest path to operating in Canada.

@hobbs-KC2G the way it is in Germany, chances are you can get your license "transcribed" to a Canadian license by Canadian authorities, for an administrative fee, instead of having to re-take a test..
